# The use of FlowAttributeChangeEvent in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, api, visual-workflow, event

I have a lwc which is used in a flow.

I have several variables from the lwc that are exposed to the flow. 
I need to make the flow know when these variables changes, so according to documentation I need to use FlowAttributeChangeEvent.

Say my code looks something like this:

```
@api apiOne
@api apiTwo
@api apiThree
buttonclick(event) {
//something happens

    const variable1 = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('apiOne' , this.apiOne);
    this.dispatchEvent(variable1);
}
```

My questions is, how do I do something similar to the remaining attributes, apiTwo, apiThree etc? Supposing I do not wish to create several FlowAttributeChangeEvent. Is it possible to accommodate all these attributes to the same FlowAttributeChangeEvent? I read somewhere that this was not possible and I have been trying myself, but without any luck. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need multiple events, but you can do this programmatically if you wanted to:

```
["apiOne", "apiTwo", "apiThree"].forEach((prop) =>
  this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent(prop, this[prop]))
);
```

Or, you could set an attribute on an input element, etc. The main advantage of JavaScript is is can be dynamic, so you don't necessarily need to have each attribute in a different method.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. 
So does that mean i would have to say something like: 

const attributeChange1 = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('apiOne' , this.apiOne);
    this.dispatchEvent(variable1);

const attributeChange2 = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('apiTwo' , this.apiTwo);
    this.dispatchEvent(attributeChange2);

and so on

or something similar to what you suggested?

How come this cant be created just using a single event?

Comment: @AndersenAnd No, you can't use a single event, but you also don't need to write all that code. I demonstrated how you can dispatch multiple events using just a couple of lines of code.

Comment: hi again sfdcfox, 
my comment was meant for why its not possible, since its possible to pass multiple parameters to custom events. 
I appreciate your answer, it was very helpful, thanks a lot. 
I have voted it as best answer and I will try what you have mentioned.

Comment: @AndersenAnd for custom events, sure, but this is a standard event that has a standard signature. You can't alter its behavior.